React Native Firebase app compiling but refusing to run after adding firebase packages
Relatively new to react native development so bear with my ignorance. Just started to add react native firebase to my RN project (with expo router) to add authentication through email and through google's own Oauth. In the beginning, I had issues with building the app correctly as I hadn't put bits in the Podfile in the iOS directory. Ended up sorting that, so now it builds with no issues, both locally and using eas.
I seem to get an issue when it first runs on the iOS sim. This is the error it's throwing:

Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
if (_Platform.default.OS === 'android') {
if (_NativeAccessibilityInfo.default != null) {
_NativeAccessibilityInfo.default.isReduceMotionEnabled(resolve);
} else {
reject(null);
}
} else {
if (_NativeAccessibilityManager.default != null) {
_NativeAccessibilityManager.default.getCurrentReduceMotionState(resolve, reject);
} else {
reject(null);
}
}
})')

isReduceMotionEnabled@http://10.0.136.255:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=1&transform.routerRoot=app&unstable_transformProfile=hermes-stable:10849:25
@http://10.0.136.255:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=1&transform.routerRoot=app&unstable_tran<…>



Now currently I have only been building the app for iOS, so idk why the issue lies in an android-specific code block. I'm also not using any features whatsoever related to reducedMotion.
The app compiles and runs perfectly without any RN firebase packages. The issue was only thrown AFTER installing and linking the app and auth packages. I've followed the installation steps to the letter. Then I uninstalled anything pertaining to firebase, and it reverts to building and running without issue. Downgraded versions don't seem to work either.
I can't find any similar issues on any forums, and I'm tearing my hair out. Please tell me if I need to include any other files, but as far as I can see its not an issue with my own code (could be wrong tho)
